# how to pass an object to a function and return the outcome back to the original function

Tags: javascript

So I am parsing a csv file which has an address object.  I then want to take that address and send it to another function I have which goes to a website and gets the lat/lng for the address.  I then want that function to return the lat/lng and add it as a child object of the location object in the array.

What I have so far is the CSV being parsed and pulling out the address object.  and I have the function that is able to send the address and get the lat/lng....but I dont know how to elegantly link them together.  I figured I could just make just 1 giant function but I want to make it cleaner.

my incident array looks like this:

```
 reportType: 'OFFENSE 2.0',                                                    
  reportNumber: '15021912',                                                     
  offense: '3301',                                                              
  description: 'Driving on Right Side of Roadway.',                             
  dateTime: '02/06/2015',                                                       
  location:                                                                     
   { block: '02:03 Greentree Rd & Mansfield Ave',                               
     zone: 'Outside City' },                                                    
  person: { age: 'OSC', sex: 'N/A' } }
```

Code for CSV parse is here.

```
function makeURL() {
    var date = new Date();
    var today = date.getDay();
    var day = daysOfTheWeek[today];
    link = 'http://apps.pittsburghpa.gov/police/arrest_blotter/arrest_blotter_' + day + '.csv'
    return link
}

var url = makeURL();
function getURL() {
    http.get(url, function(res) {
        if(res.statusCode === 200) {
            res.pipe(parser);
        } else {
            console.error('The address is unavailable. (%d)', res.statusCode);
        }
    })
}
var parser = parse(function(err, data) {
    for(i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
        var info = data[i]
        if(info[7] === 'OSC') {
            info[7] = 'Outside City Limits'
        }
        if(info[9] === '') {
            info[9] = 'N/A'
        }
        if(info[8] === '') {
            info[8] = 'N/A'
        }
        var incident = {
            reportType: info[0],
            reportNumber: info[1],
            offense: info[2],
            description: info[3],
            dateTime: info[4],
            location: {
                block: info[5] + " " + info[6],
                zone: info[7],
            },
            person: {
                age: info[8],
                sex: info[9]
            }
        }
        var passLoc = info[5];
        passLoc = passLoc.replace('block ','')
        passLoc = passLoc.replace(/ /g,"+")
        console.log(incident);
//         console.log(passLoc);
    }
});
```

Code for getting the Lat/lng is here:

```
function getLoc() {
    for(i = 0; i < locy.length; i++) {
        var address = locy[i]
        var url = "http://geodata.alleghenycounty.us/arcgis/rest/services/Geocoders/EAMS_Composite_Loc/GeocodeServer/findAddressCandidates?Street=" + address + "&City=Pittsburgh&State=PA&ZIP=&SingleLine=&outFields=&outSR=4326&searchExtent=&f=pjson";
        http.get(url, function(res) {
            var data = '';
            res.on('data', function(chunk) {
                data += chunk;
            });
            res.on('end', function() {
                var d = JSON.parse(data);
                var obj = d.candidates;
                if(obj != '') {
                    var loc = obj[0].location
                    var location = {
                        lat: loc.x,
                        lng: loc.y
                    }
                    return location
                } else {
                    return address
                }
            });
            res.on('error', function(err) {
                console.log("error!")
            });
        });
    }
}
```

if there is an even better way to do this that I am not thinking about always willing to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly do your location objects look like? It's a bit hack-y, but associative arrays/dictionaries might help you out here.

Let's say you make a few location objects (done in Chrome's dev console, so you can see what each statement returns).

Start by creating one location object:

```
place1 = {}
>Object {}
place1.name = "SomePlace"
>"SomePlace"
place1.address = "123 Sesame St."
>"123 Sesame St."
```

Then, for good measure, create another:

```
place2 = {}
>Object {}
place2.name = "AnotherPlace"
>"AnotherPlace"
place2.address = "456 Main St."
>"456 Main St."
```

Now, let your `locy` array hold these locations:

```
locy = []
>[]
locy.push(place1)
>1
locy
>[Object]
locy.push(place2)
>2
locy[1]
>Object {name: "AnotherPlace", address: "456 Main St."}
```

Now, you can just append to those objects on the fly:

```
locy[1].lat = 35
>35
locy[1]
>Object {name: "AnotherPlace", address: "456 Main St.", lat: 35}
```

So in your case, just populate `locy` with objects like this, and pass it into your `getLoc()` function. Then, you can still iterate over it with a for loop, and associate the lat/lon data with your `locy[i]` or `address` variable.

Comment: I added what my array looks like in my question.  This makes sense, i might have been over thinking it...

Comment: but is there a way to just have the function return the value and then add it to the incident array? or should i just have the 2nd function add it to the array.